# How to use a pointer in nested functions in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to correct this program, but until now I just have made a change to using the function "dotprod", but there is something when the function of "activity" is used, I cannot evaluate the part to get the output, the error I got was a Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. It seems to be a problem with the pointers, so I tried some changes but I always got an error. If someone could give me an advice about it please. 
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


double dotprod( int n, double *vec1, double *vec2)
// n Length of vectors
// vec 1 One of the vectors to be dotted
//vec 2The other vector
{
 int k, m;
 double sum;

 sum=0.0;   //Will cumulate dot product here
 k=n/4;     //Divide into this many groups of 4
 m=n%4;     //This is the remainder of thet division


 while(k--){       //Do each group of 4
  sum += *(vec1) * *(vec2);
  for (int j=1; j<4; j++){
  sum += *(vec1+j) * *(vec2+j);
  }
  *(vec1) += 4;
  *(vec2) += 4;
  }

 while (m--){   //Do the remainder
  sum += *(vec1++) * *(vec2++);
 }
 return sum;
}


void activity(          //Implement Equation
  double *input,        //This neuron's input vector, ninputs long
  double *coefs,        //Weigth vector,ninputs+1 long(bias is at end)
  double *output,       //Achieved activation of this neuron
  int ninputs,          //Number of inputs
  int outlin            //Activation function is identity if nonzero, else logistic
  )
{
  double sum;


  double sumtotal;
  sum=dotprod(ninputs,(double *)input,(double *)coefs);
  sumtotal=sum+coefs[ninputs];   //Bias ter

    double param, resultado;
    param = sumtotal;
    resultado = exp (-param);
    printf ("The exponential value of %f is %f.\n", param, resultado );

  if(outlin)
    *(output)=sum;
   else
    *(output)=1.0/(1.0+param);
}


static void trial_thr(
  double *input,        //input vector n_model_inputs long
  int n_all,            //Number of layers, including output, not including input
  int n_model_inputs,   //Number of inputs to the model
  double *outputs,      //Output vector of the model, ntarg long
  int ntarg,            //Number of outputs
  int *nhid_all,        //nhid_all[i] is the number of hidden neurons in hidden layer i
  double *weigths_opt[],//Weigths_opt[i] points to the weigth vector for hidden layer i
  double *hid_act[],    //hid_act[i] points to the vector of activations of hideen layer i
  double *final_layer_weigths,  //Weigths of final layer
  int classifier        //If nonzero use SoftMax output; else use linear output
  )
{
  int i, ilayer;
  double sum;

    for(ilayer=0;ilayer<n_all;ilayer++){

     if(ilayer==0 && n_all==1){        //Direct input to output? (No hidden)
       for(i=0;i<ntarg;i++)
         activity((double *)input,final_layer_weigths+i*(n_model_inputs+1),
                  outputs+i,n_model_inputs,1);
       }

     else if(ilayer==0){               //First hidden layer?
        for(i=0;i<nhid_all[ilayer];i++){
            std::cout<< "Contador : " << i << std::endl;
            activity((double *)input,weigths_opt[ilayer]+i*(n_model_inputs+1),
                    hid_act[ilayer]+i,n_model_inputs,0);
        }
     }

     else if(ilayer<n_all-1){          //Subsequent hiden layer?
       for(i=0;i<nhid_all[ilayer];i++)
         activity(hid_act[ilayer-1],weigths_opt[ilayer]+i*(nhid_all[ilayer-1]+1),
                  hid_act[ilayer]+i,nhid_all[ilayer-1],0);
       }

     else{
       for(i=0;i<ntarg;i++)
         activity(hid_act[ilayer-1],final_layer_weigths+i*(nhid_all[ilayer-1]+1),
                  outputs+i,nhid_all[ilayer-1],1);
       }
     }

    if(classifier){ //Classifier is always SoftMax(Equation(2.12)con page 22)
       sum=0.0;
       for(i=0;i<ntarg;i++){     //For all outputs
         if(outputs[i]<300.0)    //SoftMax can occasionally produce huge outputs
            outputs[i]=exp(outputs[i]);
         else
            outputs[i]=exp(300.0);
         sum+=outputs[i];
         }
       for(i=0;i<ntarg;i++)
         outputs[i]/=sum;
       }
    }


    int main(void)  {
    double b[4][1] = { 1, 2, 5, 7 };
    double c[4][1] = { 1, 4, 8, 2 };
    double result;
    double a[2][19];

    int i;
    i=0;

    a[0][0] = -2;
    a[0][1] = -2;
    a[0][2] = -1;
    a[0][3] = 0;
    a[0][4] = 1;
    a[0][5] = 1;
    a[0][6] = 2;
    a[0][7] = 2;
    a[0][8] = 2;
    a[0][9] = 3;

    a[1][0] = 2;
    a[1][1] = 4;
    a[1][2] = -4;
    a[1][3] = 3;
    a[1][4] = -2;
    a[1][5] = 0;
    a[1][6] = -3;
    a[1][7] = 0;
    a[1][8] = 2;
    a[1][9] = 0;

    int n_all=2;
    int n_model_inputs=10;
    double *outputs;
    int ntarg=1;
    int nhid_all=3;
    double *weigths_op;
    double *hid_act;
    double final_layer_weigths;
    int classifier=1;


    for(i;i<=9;i++){
        printf("%4.5f, %4.5f\n",a[0][i],a[1][i]);
    }
    result=dotprod(4,*c,*b);
    printf("\n This is the result : %4.5f \n ", result);

    trial_thr( (double *)a, n_all, n_model_inputs, outputs, ntarg, &nhid_all, &weigths_op, &hid_act,
             &final_layer_weigths, classifier);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Please don't use C tag for C++ and vice versa.

Comment: Which line caused the segfault? (If you don't know, use a debugger)

Comment: @Olaf Personally, I hate that pedantry, when the underlying problem is the same in either language. The question and answer could be useful to both C++ and C programmers.

Comment: @immibis: Tell your compiler to be less pedantic. It really should not care so much if you miss a semicolon, use a slightly wrong type, etc. I'm still waiting for the "-do-what-i-want-not-what-i-write` compiler-option.

Comment: @Olaf Compilers are not the target audience of Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `double* weights_opt` is never initialized but you pass it first to `trial_thr` and then later in the part of first hidden layer to `activity`, which calls the `dotprod` and crashes when it tries to read from the variable first time on line

```
 sum += *(vec1) * *(vec2);
```

Also there is a bug in dot prod. It should be

```
double dotprod( int n, double *vec1, double *vec2)
  // n Length of vectors
  // vec 1 One of the vectors to be dotted
  //vec 2The other vector
{
  int k, m;
  double sum;

  sum=0.0;   //Will cumulate dot product here
  k=n/4;     //Divide into this many groups of 4
  m=n%4;     //This is the remainder of thet division


  while(k--){       //Do each group of 4
    sum += *(vec1) * *(vec2);
    for (int j=1; j<4; j++){
      sum += *(vec1+j) * *(vec2+j);
    }
    vec1 += 4; //HERE: you need to increase the address not the value.
    vec2 += 4;
  }

  while (m--){   //Do the remainder
    sum += *(vec1++) * *(vec2++);
  }
  return sum; 
}
```

Though I would write the first while loop just

```
while(k--){       //Do each group of 4
  for (int j=0;j<4;++j){
    sum += *(vec1++) * *(vec2++);
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer it helped me a little bit, but as you mention it the problem is when i try to handle the function "trial_thr", besides you mention "weights_opt" is never initialized in the function "dotprod" the value of sum is some way zero which is at the begining good, but when it tries to evaluate "output = 1.0/(1.0 + param)" the program crashes.